# Failing to update packages in R ('make' not found)

Tags: r

I am getting this warning

```
Warning in system(cmd) : 'make' not found
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'xfun'
* removing 'C:/Users/mbosn/Dropbox/My PC (LAPTOP-FJK21ACS)/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/xfun'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/mbosn/Dropbox/My PC (LAPTOP-FJK21ACS)/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/xfun'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘xfun’ had non-zero exit status
```

I saw suggestion to update r tools to the latest version, which I did but I'm still getting the same warning.

Comment: Make sure that your version of RTools matches your version of R. It looks like you're using version 4.0 of R so you'd need version rtools40 (not the latest version)